# -[TEST_BUNDLE FAILED_TO_START] xctool CocoaPods testing failure

Tags: ios, cocoapods, travis-ci, xctool

I'm running into a very peculiar issue with testing a new cocoapods repo on Travis-Ci. The build is verified to work on my machine, and the only external deps are specta, and expecta.

The build keeps failing with the following errors.

     `[Info] Collecting info for testables... (3053 ms)
  run-test Tests.xctest (iphonesimulator8.0, application-test)
    [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'org.cocoapods.demo.SHMKit' but failed. (160 ms)
    [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 2 more times (0 ms)
    [Info] Shut down iOS Simulator... (0 ms)
    [Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (124 ms)
    [Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings at path "/Users/travis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BDBABE28-2772-44DF-AC46-F449E44F4CCD/data" (361 ms)
    [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'org.cocoapods.demo.SHMKit' but failed. (37 ms)
    [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 1 more time (0 ms)
    [Info] Shut down iOS Simulator... (0 ms)
    [Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (124 ms)
    [Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings at path "/Users/travis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BDBABE28-2772-44DF-AC46-F449E44F4CCD/data" (255 ms)
    [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'org.cocoapods.demo.SHMKit' but failed. (23 ms)
    [Warning] Preparing test environment failed. (0 ms)
      -[TEST_BUNDLE FAILED_TO_START]
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
There was a problem starting the test bundle: Simulator 'iPhone 4s' was not prepared: Failed for unknown reason.
━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━`

I've tweaked xctool with -freshSimulator, -freshInstall, -destination 'iPhone 5,OS=7.1' and 'iPhone 6, OS=8.0'. I've created new schemes, and had the same issue as well. I'm also updating cocoapods, and xctool to latest on the build script.

It's an open source project and can be found here. https://travis-ci.org/mdobson/SHMKit-CocoaPods

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to fix my build!

Comment: Which version of xctool are you using? Only v0.2 and v0.2.1 are compatible with Xcode6. Check the releases page for information: https://github.com/facebook/xctool/releases .

Comment: I'm using v0.2. I completely blanked on this question. Turns out it was platform issues on Travis-CI and their upgrade to XCode 6. At time of this writing everything is good to go.